# How do I find the number of bit strings with 3 consecutive 0s in a bit string of length n?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, permutations

Say n is 8.

How would I ever solve this problem? I've Googled around and searched this site but I haven't come up with much. I'm not even looking for the answer necessarily, just the process by which I'd go about getting it.

I started by calculating the total number of bit strings of length 8 as $2^8$. From there where should I go?

Comment: Would you count $0000$ as containing 3 consecutive $0$s or are you limiting the count to those strings that contain 3 consecutive $0$s and no more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define $A(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ not containing three $0$'s and ending in $1$, $B(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ not containing three $0$'s and ending in one $0$, , $C(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ not containing three $0$'s and ending in two
 $0$'s, and $D(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ containing three zeros.  Then $A(1)=1$, $B(1)=1$, $C(1)=0$, $D(1)=0$ and for $n>1$,
$$
\begin{align}
A(n)&=A(n-1)+B(n-1)+C(n-1) \\ 
B(n)&=A(n-1)\\
C(n)&=B(n-1)\\ 
D(n)&=2D(n-1)+C(n-1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Doug Smith:  This answer presumes that you want to count all strings with at least one run of at least three zeros.

Comment: I edited your answer since in my browser some of the text overlapped the "Related" items on the right of the page. Feel free to revert if you wish.

Comment: @RickDecker:  I find the $\LaTeX$ grows during editing and refreshing the question often brings it back to size.  But this is fine.

Comment: Unless I misread, I got $D(4)=2$ but there are three such strings of length 4: $0000$, $0001$, $1000$.

Comment: @RickDecker:  Yes, I lost the coefficient of $2$ on $D$.  You can add either a zero or one to a string that already has three zeros.

Comment: FWIW, this is Sloan's A050231.

Comment: @Rick, the founder of the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences is spelled **Sloane**, not Sloan. Also, [link](http://oeis.org/A050231).

Comment: Not containing three zeros and ending in one. What does the ending in one part have to do with anything?

Comment: @DougSmith:  Ending in one means ending in the character one, not ending in one zero.  That is how I make sure I got all the strings and keep track of how many zeros are needed to make three.  The A strings need three zeros in a row to be acceptable.  The B's need either two immediately or a run of three later (going through being an A).  The C's need either one more zero or a run of three later.  The D's are already there.